# Airflow - bash command not running

Tags: airflow

I have the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.decorators import task,dag
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

args = {
    'owner': 'Harry',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2022,1,1)
}
    
@dag(default_args=args,schedule_interval="@once",description='Task da runcode do professor',catchup=False,tags=['runcode'])
    def runcode():
    
        @task
        def start():
            print('inicio da carga dos dados.')
        
        @task
        def cria_parquet():
            BashOperator(
            task_id = 'chama arquivo',
            bash_command='/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /opt/airflow/dags/prova.py'
        )
    
        instancia_inicio = start()
        instancia_cria_parquet = cria_parquet()
    
        instancia_inicio >> instancia_cria_parquet
    
execucao = runcode()
```

Why do my `bash_command` isn't working? I have tried a few changes, but no sucesses.

It shows as "success". But actually the code inside the script insn't executed. And it works fine when I execute directly in bash terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your dag on Airflow 2.4.1, I got syntax error for task cria_parquet stating "the key 'chama arquivo' has to be made of alphanumeric characters, dashes, dots and underscores exclusively"

after changing it to chama_arquivo, I was able to run it.

Comment: I have done this correction already. no syntax error, but python content is not executed.

Comment: I'm running airflow using docker-compose, for troubleshooting such issues, I run scripts from within worker/scheduler containers. for testing your dag, I created a very basic python script, it ran fine.  how is  your airflow set up done i.e. local direct install or docker/k8?